# Import secret keys created in Kleopatra with Windows 11 to Ubuntu

Tags: kleopatra

I exported and imported a secret key pair in asc file created in Windows 11 and it was successfully imported in Kleopatra Ubuntu, but when trying to decrypt a file signed in Windows with the same key it gives an error, is it only decryptable in Windows even though the private key Is it correct in Ubuntu?

Check importing from Ubuntu to Windows 11 and the error only works from Windows to Ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Signed files aren't decrypted, and don't use or need the secret key (as PGP and thus Kleo/GnuPG calls it). _Encrypted_ files are and do. Kleo is just a GUI that runs GnuPG (either gpg[2] or gpgsm depending) behind the curtain. On Ubuntu run gpg manually -- at a terminal/shell `gpg -d Kayros.txt.gpg` with pathnames if needed -- and it will likely give more useful (or at least extensive) error info.

Comment: There is no error message, only data at 0    gpg -d Kayros.txt.gpg
gpg: enabled debug flags: memstat
gpg: keydb: handles=3 locks=0 parse=3 get=3
gpg:        build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg:        reset=0 found=3 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=8 cached=8 good=8 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: rndjent stat: collector=0x0000000000000000 calls=0 bytes=0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/65536 bytes in 0 blocks

Comment: Adding route gpg --verify /home/usernet/Documentos/Kayros.txt.gpg
gpg: enabled debug flags: memstat
gpg: verify signatures failed: Error inesperado
gpg: keydb: handles=0 locks=0 parse=0 get=0
gpg: build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg: reset=0 found=0 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=0 cached=0 good=0 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: rndjent stat: collector=0x0000000000000000 calls=0 bytes=0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/65536 bytes in 0 blocks

Comment: The first result was made from
cd /home/usernet/Documents/ and then gpg -d Kayros.txt.gpg, it does not show an error message.
The second result does show an error executing with the file path gpg --verify /home/usernet/Documents/Kayros.txt.gpg but it is the same as what kleopatra shows, only an unexpected or unknown error.

Comment: I've never seen gpg behave like that; it appears to be mishandling options, at least in the first case. Just in case, try `--decrypt` instead of `-d`, although those _should_ be identical. If that doesn't fix it, check if your environment has gpg re-defined by a shell function or alias or a script, or some nonstandard version installed -- `type gpg` in shell -- and if ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf exists look to see if it has anything weird in it.

Comment: gpg --decrypt /home/usernet/Documentos/Kayros.txt.gpg
gpg: enabled debug flags: memstat
gpg: keydb: handles=3 locks=0 parse=3 get=3
gpg:        build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg:        reset=0 found=3 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=8 cached=8 good=8 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: rndjent stat: collector=0x0000000000000000 calls=0 bytes=0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/65536 bytes in 0 blocks
usernet@equipo:~$  cd /home/usernet/Documentos

Comment: ###+++--- GPGConf ---+++###
utf8-strings
debug-level basic
log-file socket:///home/usernet/.gnupg/log-socket
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++### lun 23 oct 2023 13:50:55 -03
# GPGConf edited this configuration file.
# It will disable options before this marked block, but it will
# never change anything below these lines.

Comment: cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

Comment: pro security-status
2124 packages installed:
     1690 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
     423 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
     9 packages from third parties
     2 packages no longer available for download

Comment: gpg -h
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: Ah, `debug-level basic` in `gpg.conf` does cause the extra output -- but it should not prevent the decrypt. The closest I can come is to try to decrypt an empty file, but that gives an error for 'Unknown system error' -- not very specific or helpful, but still different from what you get. If your file is not actually sensitive (i.e. only test data) or you can reproduce with such a file, can you post it? (Since .gpg files are binary, use hex or base64 encoding, or something like pastebin, to provide accurate contents.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, the errors are the same for all files regardless of their content (carry out tests, short or long texts, they generate errors) a txt file is created in Windows 11, it is signed with Kleoparta, it is exported to Ubuntu and generated mistake.

Comment: and same error LibreOffice odt file extension